Contraction: from implicit to explicit definition
In the book "Geometric Algebra for Computer Science" by Leo Dorst et al., the implicit definition is defined in Eq. (3.6), by $$(X\wedge A)*B=X*(A\rfloor B),$$ where "$\rfloor$" is the left contraction and "\wedge" is the wedge product. Then explicit definition is given via a list of equations (3.7---3.11) and is claimed that this explicit definition "agrees with the implicit definition (3.6)".
Appendix B.2 proves (3.7--3.11) by assuming (3.6), but I could not find the other direction.
What am I missing? Is it trivial? The proof in the appendix is very involved.
Maybe "agrees" means only one side of "if and only if"?
Edit: Following the comment, I add the "explicit definition" from the book, as well as "scalar product":  

This is going to boil down to the fact that $$\langle AB\rangle = AB = \langle A\mathbin\rfloor B\rangle$$ or in particular $$AB = A\mathbin\rfloor B$$ when $A,B$ are homogeneous with the same grade. (Maybe some reversals need to be thrown in, I don't know what convention you're using.)

Right, I thought about it. However, there are two issues: (i) I could not prove the claim that you wrote. The proof in the book is based on (3.6), and (ii) Your observation does not handle the case where the blades have different degrees.

What is your "explicit" definition? Is it in terms of $v\rfloor$ being an antiderivation for vector $v$, or is it in terms of grade selection of the geometric product? Or something else? Also, what is your definition of scalar product?

"Your observation does not handle the case where the blades have different degree" Yes it does, that is my first equation, which easily follows from the second when you know how $\rfloor$ effects grade and that the only nonzero scalar products are between multivectors of the same grade.

@Nicholas, many thanks for your time and patience, and apologies for my ignorance. I am totally new in this business and my only knowledge is based on the first 4 chapters of the book. This is why I still do not know the meaning of the "<>" that you used. However, according to the book, I thought that it should be possible to prove the claim with the current notation. I also added the requested definitions in the hope that you can give me more hints.

By $\langle X\rangle$ I mean the scalar part. This or $\langle X\rangle_0$ is typical GA notation, I would be surprised if it's not anywhere in your book.

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
\newcommand\grade{\mathop{\mathbf{grade}}}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
$First we prove that
$$
  A*B = \form{A\lcontr B}
\tag{$*$}
$$
for all multivectors $A,B$.
We prove ($*$) for blades $A, B$ and then extend by linearity. From (3.10), (3.11), and factoring $A$ into vectors, we conclude that
$$
  \grade(A\lcontr B) = \begin{cases} \grade(B) - \grade(A) &\text{if }\grade(B) \geq \grade(A), \\ 0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
It follows that if $\grade(A) \ne \grade(B)$
$$
  \form{A\lcontr B} = 0
$$
just like $A*B$, so we now consider the case $k := \grade(A) = \grade(B)$. Note that in this case
$$
  \form{A\lcontr B} = A\lcontr B.
$$
We proceed by induction on $k$. When $k=0$ everything is just scalar multiplication so ($*$) is trivial. Now suppose it holds for $k$. Factor $A$ and $B$ into
$$
  A = A'\wedge a_{k+1},\quad B = b_1\wedge B'
$$
for $k$-blades $A',B'$ and vectors $a_{k+1},b_1$. By (3.10) and (3.11),
$$
  A\lcontr B = (a_{k+1}\cdot b_1)A'\lcontr B' - A'\lcontr(b_1\wedge(a_{k+1}\lcontr B')).
$$
Applying the inductive hypothesis turns this into
$$
  (a_{k+1}\cdot b_1)A'*B' - A'*(b_1\wedge(a_{k+1}\lcontr B')). 
$$
Writing $B' = b_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge b_{k+1}$ and applying (3.10) repeatedly yields
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}(a_{k+1}\cdot b_i)A'*(b_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge b_{i-1}\wedge b_{i+1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge b_{k+1}). 
$$
If you stare at this long enough, you will realize that this is Laplace expansion of the determinant in (3.2) along the last row, thus proving ($*$).

Now that we have ($*$), (3.6) is just (3.11):
$$
  A*(B\lcontr C) = \form{A\lcontr(B\lcontr C)} = \form{(A\wedge B)\lcontr C} = (A\wedge B)*C.
$$
